# Java keystore located in tomcat lib

Tags: java, tomcat, keystore, rampart

Are there any security implications of having a java keystore in the lib folder of Tomcat? I tried to have it outside of the lib folder but then I get a file not found exception. This is for an Axis2 web service in combination with Rampart so I am not getting the keystore programmatically but only giving a name.

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to place your .keystore fiel in a particualr directory. You can place your .keystore file anywhere as mentioned by the tomcat documentaion. So make sure when you put the keystore in a different location, you mention the path correctly. Also if you are creating a new store in a different location then you may have to import the certificates in the new keystore.  This is what tomcat documentation say about creating a keystore in a specified location:

> To specify a different location or filename, add the -keystore
>   parameter, followed by the complete pathname to your keystore file, to
>   the keytool command shown above. You will also need to reflect this
>   new location in the server.xml configuration file, as described later.
>   For example:
>
> Windows:
>
> ```
>        %JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA \   -keystore \path\to\my\keystore
> ```
>
> Unix:
>
> ```
>        $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA \   -keystore /path/to/my/keystore
> ```